# How to state that command on one subproject depends on command in another subproject in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `.scala` build definition set up as follows:

```
object build extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("main", file(".")) aggregate(benchmark)
  lazy val benchmark = Project("benchmark", file("benchmark"))
}
```

I need to run `re-start` task on `main` project before running `run` task on `benchmark` (so I need to ensure that `benchmark/run` triggers `main/re-start`). Is there a way to specify such dependency?

EDIT: Seems I found the solution, so I will add it to this question in case somebody runs into the same problem. The idea is to create a custom version of reStart task, making it a Task instead of InputTask, since we don't need to parse arguments. The full build.scala is as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import cc.spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.Revolver._
import cc.spray.revolver.Actions._
import cc.spray.revolver.AppProcess

object build extends Build {
  val noArgs = TaskKey[ExtraCmdLineOptions]("no-args")
  val noArgsTask = TaskKey[ExtraCmdLineOptions]("no-args") := { ExtraCmdLineOptions(Nil, Nil) }
  val reStartCustom = TaskKey[AppProcess]("re-start-custom")

  val reStartTask = reStartCustom <<= (streams, state, reForkOptions, mainClass in reStart, fullClasspath in Runtime, reStartArgs, noArgs in root)
    .map(restartApp)
    .updateState(registerAppProcess)
    .dependsOn(products in Compile)

  lazy val root: Project = Project("main", file("."), settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(noArgsTask, reStartTask)) aggregate(benchmark)
  lazy val benchmark: Project = Project("benchmark", file("benchmark"), settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    run in Compile <<= (reStartCustom in root, run in Compile in benchmark) {
      case (mainRestart, benchmarkRun) =>
        benchmarkRun.mapTask { runTask => mainRestart.flatMap(_ => runTask) }
    }
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be nicer ways to do it, but here is my take on it:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyKeys {
  val restart = TaskKey[Unit]("re-start")
}

object build extends Build {
  import MyKeys._
  lazy val root: Project = Project("main",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      restart := { println("***RESTART***") }
    )
  ) aggregate(benchmark)
  lazy val benchmark: Project = Project(
    "benchmark",
    file("benchmark"),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      run  in Compile <<= (restart in root, run in Compile in benchmark){
        case (mainRestart, benchmarkRun) =>
          benchmarkRun.mapTask{ runTask => mainRestart.flatMap{ _ => runTask }
        }
      }
    )
  )
}
```

With this setup, `sbt "project benchmark" run` will first run the `restart` task on the `main` project, and then actually invoke the standard `run` command on project `benchmark`.

Note that I added a `restart`  TaskKey (and a dummy implementation in `main`) for illustration.

As you can see, this looks a bit involved for such a simple requirement, but it is my (limited) experience that working with `InputTask`s/`InputKey`s (`run` being one) is always much more tricky than it ought to be (as opposed to plain `Task`s/`TaskKey`s which are easier to handle).

Comment: Your example works fine, but the problem begins in the fact that mainRestart is itself an InputTask - thus compiler complains with `value flatMap is not a member of sbt.InputTask`.

Comment: Well than I'd say tough luck. I would actually love to know an easy solution. Pragmatically speaking, if you are the author of the "restart" task the best thing to do is to refactor it into two versions: an `InputTask` and a plain `Task` (obviously, both calling the same implementation for the sake of factorisation). Then use the latter when you are in such a situation.

Comment: Well, sadly, I'm no the author (the task comes from sbt-revolver plugin), so I can't :) But thanks for your help!

Comment: I managed to rewrite the task, you can see it in my question edit. Thanks for your help, again!